# Gradle Distribution Task Output Files Not at Root of ZIP

Tags: gradle, software-distribution

I created a simple Gradle build that exports the contents of ./src/main/groovy to a zip file. The zip file contains a folder with the exact same name as the zip file. I cannot figure out how to get the files into the root of the zip file using the distribution plugin.

i.e. `gradlew clean distZip` produces:

> helloDistribution-1.0.zip -> helloDistribution-1.0 -> files

what I would like:

> helloDistribution-1.0.zip -> files

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

version = '1.0'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from {
                'src/main/groovy'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have attempted to fix the problem by adding `into { 'dir' }` but to no avail.

Comment: It will not work this way. I suppose the only way for creating such hierarchy is to do it with plain old ant zip task.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `into '/'` seems to do the trick:

```
contents {
    from {
        'src/main/groovy'
    }
    into '/'
}
```

Comment: If you merely change the build.gradle and invoke `gradle distZip` you won't see the desired effect.
You have to call `gradle clean distZip`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, penfold's answer did not work for me. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
task Package(type: Zip) {

    from {
        def rootScriptFiles = [] // collection of script files at the root of the src folder
        new File('src/main/groovy/').eachFile { if (it.name.endsWith('.groovy')) rootScriptFiles.add(it) }


        ['build/libs/',                 // build binaries
         'src/res/',                    // resources
         rootScriptFiles,               // groovy root source files
        ]
    }
    baseName = pluginName
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To copy files into the root of `helloDistribution-1.0.zip -> helloDistribution-1.0 ->` use

```
contents {
    from {
        'some/file'
    }
    into ''
}
```